# WSO2 ESB run in cluster mode with message queue

Tags: spring, wso2, cluster-computing, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Good morning,
I have a WSO2 data bus (Enterprise Integrator) running in a cluster (two nodes). I have several message stores and a message processor configured on the data bus.
When I start the bus, all Scheduled Failover Message Forwarding Processors start correctly, but Scheduled Message Forwarding Processors are not active. I have to run them manually.
If two nodes are running, message processors do not download messages from the message store and do not distribute them further when I have Task Count (Cluster Mode) = 1. When I change the value to 2, the messages are forwarded, but if one of the nodes fails, all messages are duplicated.
How to properly configure the cluster so that messages are sent one at a time, even in the event of a single node failure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error was for message store in-memory, after changing to a database the problem is resolved.